# Send sms at a specific date and time in flask-restful?

Tags: python

I have an API using flask restful that stores user information like mobile number,message,date and time etc. I have to create a function that send sms to every users on their own date and time. Is there any way to do that? What are the best practices if there is more user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of approaches to this, but I would recommend Celery for this. You can set Celery to run daily, search for something like `sent=False`, and then send the message. More info here - https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: do i have to run this task for every seconds for sending the sms at exact time they specified?

Comment: It depends on how accurate you want to send the message. Also, sending large amounts of texts are "queued" by most providers.

Comment: Does it slows the server if i run the task in every seconds?

Comment: It all depends on the server and amount of query. You can spend $10/month and shouldn't be a problem. Just keep an eye on the server stats.

Comment: Absolutely. Glad to help.